# Instruct TypeScript Which Return Type is Expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a function that can return a couple of different types and I want to specify the return using an argument:

```
type returnTypes = 'string' | 'object';

function getValue(returnType: returnTypes): string | Record<string, string> {
  if(returnType === 'object') {
    return { my: 'return value' }
  }
  return 'my return value';
}

interface IData {
  myObjectValue: Record<string, string>;
  myStringValue: string;
}
const data: IData = {
  myObjectValue: getValue('object'),
  myStringValue: getValue('string'),
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAThwFcYDsAq4IGcoF4oHJNgYBLZAc3ygB8CB7AIwCsIBjYfAbgChuAzBMnYk6yKOXgA1AIYAbBBAAUcRCnSQAXLHhI0GTAEotRUhRpQASmzowAJgB4TZcgBooTigD4oAb25QoEj5lHTUMXBw8fEYWdnwDX38A7VUxHwBbEC18FV0oADc5BXwAXySygNyUAkyUvML5CC5uMu4yYAgYPmlWaABJABFpYGlEgMyAeWY2YBlGrStWGwcPV3diZ08ecZAAZQ2KOYVjA-IeMqXkIihbYektQbvcMahJ6fYjiC0JWaKlaPeHAMLiSmX2pnIn2%20Uj%20ikIp3iILKQA)

The assignment to `data` gets me the following errors:

> Type 'string | Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.

> Type 'string | Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type
> 'string'.   Type 'Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type
> 'string'

presumably because TypeScript thinks the return value of `getValue` is wider than the types defined in my interface.

### How can I instruct TypeScript based on my `returnType` argument, which of the two return types I will receive?

(Or is there a more canonical way to do this, eg just separate into functions, if so what/how?

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible, because the typing system is purely a compile-time system, with no run-time effects. Testing what `returnType` is happens only at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use overloads...

```
function getValue(returnType: 'object'): Record<string, string>
function getValue(returnType: 'string'): string
function getValue(returnType: 'string' | 'object'): string | Record<string, string> {
  if(returnType === 'object') {
    return {my: 'return value'}
  }
  return 'my return value';
}

interface IData {
  myObjectValue: Record<string, string>;
  myStringValue: string;
}
const data: IData = {
  myObjectValue: getValue('object'),
  myStringValue: getValue('string'),
}
```

Or a generic with conditional return type but will have to make assertions in the implementation while returning...

```
type returnTypes = 'string' | 'object';

function getValue<T extends returnTypes>(returnType: T): T extends 'string' ? string : Record<string, string> {
  if(returnType === 'object') {
    return {my: 'return value'} as any
  }
  return 'my return value' as any;
}

interface IData {
  myObjectValue: Record<string, string>;
  myStringValue: string;
}
const data: IData = {
  myObjectValue: getValue('object'),
  myStringValue: getValue('string'),
}
```

Comment: What does this mean: `T extends 'string' ? string : Record<string, string>` ?

Comment: @1252748 It's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). I simpler terms you can interpret it as "If `T` is `'string'` return `string` else `Record<string, string>`". If the `'string'` part is confusing you can write as `T extends 'object' ? Record<string, string> : string` too

Answer (score 1):

The typescript compiler does not infer the returntype of the function by the value of parameters you are passing in. That would only be evaluated at runtime.

So it always assumes the returned type to be `string | Record<string, string>`. What you can do, is using a [Type Assertion](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-assertion) at the receiving site, to tell typescript, what type to expect.

```
type returnTypes = 'string' | 'object';

function getValue(returnType: returnTypes): string | Record<string, string> {
  if(returnType === 'object') {
    return { my: 'return value' }
  }
  return 'my return value';
}

interface IData {
  myObjectValue: Record<string, string>;
  myStringValue: string;
}
const data: IData = {
  myObjectValue: getValue('object') as Record<string, string>,
  myStringValue: getValue('string') as string,
}
```

Of course, such type asserations are not a guarantee, that this will work at runtime. Because if your `getValue` method has an error and you return a `string` even if the parameter is `object`, this will lead to follow up errors, when you try to access `myObjectvalue.my`

The "cleanest" solution of would probably be, to define two distinct functions, one returning a `string` the other one returning a `Record<string, string>`